# Get number of arguments of a function

Tags: sass

I receive a function as an argument of another function, and would like to know the number of its arguments. Is this possible?

For example:

```
@function foo($list, $fn) {
  if (number-of-arguments($fn) == 1) { // looking for this kinda magic
    // ...
  }
}
```

---

Just in order to avoid a XY-problem, and in case the above is not possible, what I'm trying to do is to ignore an error with `call` and giving extra arguments: `call($fn, $arg1, $arg2)` will fail if `$fn` is defined to take in only one argument. It currently fails with this: `Error: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) for 'fn'`. I also hoped for a try/catch mechanism but there's no such concept in Sass either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no introspection function to do that but you could do a map based validation like:

```
//  dummy functions 
@function fn1($a){ @return $a; }
@function fn2($a, $b){ @return $a + $b; }
@function fn3($a, $b, $c){ @return $a + $b + $c; }

@function foo(
  $fn,      // function name as string
  $args...  // arglist 
){

  //  arguments passed
  $args-passed: length($args); 

  //  arguments required by functions
  $args-required: map-get((
    fn1: 1, // fn1 takes 1 argument
    fn2: 2, // fn2 takes 2 arguments
    fn3: 3  // fn3 takes 3 arguments
  ), $fn);

  //  match => make call
  //  no match => throw warning or error or do something else
  @if $args-passed == $args-required {
    @return call($fn, $args...);
  } @else {
    @warn 'function `#{$fn}` requires #{$args-required} arguments #{$args-passed} were passed ';
    @return null;
  }
}


test {
    value-1: foo(fn1, 1);    
    value-2: foo(fn2, 1, 2); 
    value-3: foo(fn3, 1, 2);  
}
```

Output:

```
test {
    value-1: 1;
    value-2: 3;
    // value-3 receives null and is not printed but a warning is thrown
    // "function `fn3` requires 3 arguments 2 were passed" 
}
```